# Recovering lost space due to PhotoRec

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk, photorec

I accidentally deleted a important folder, and attempted to use testdisk (photorec) to recover the files.

However, it kept taking longer and longer so I stopped it. It created 18 folders in home, then deleted them. However, it never returned my space. I previously had 276GB of space, but I now only have only 101GB of space.

Is there a way I can get back my 175GB of space, or to have to do a complete wipe and reinstall Ubuntu?

If a complete wipe and reinstall is necessary, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I have recovered the 175GB of space by using BleachBit (as root).

Tick all  the boxes.